# Update child value in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase structure:

```
 "Requests" : {
"-KiyT2fiL8dE3jh7ccWT" : {
  "4pGOtqaTskarMnvz058UBpYbW1y2" : {
    "address" : "Street 12",
    "phone" : "05****699",
    "status" : "status",
    "subject" : "subjectText",
    "teacherName" : "nameText",
    "time_date" : "30 Apr 2017 1:46:43 p.m.",
    "uid_user" : "4pGOtqaTskarMnvz058UBpYbW1y2"
  }
```

I'm trying to update a value of child `" status"`, How to get to `"status"` in `rootRef`? 
This my code

```
Acceptable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Unacceptable.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(context, " this Request has been Acceptable " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Requests");

                     rootRef.child("Requests").child("uid").child("uid_user").orderByChild("status").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                             final String  status = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                             System.out.println(status);
                             rootRef.child("status").setValue("Your Request has been Acceptable");


                         }

                         @Override
                         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                         }
                     });
                    Toast.makeText(context, " this Request has been Acceptable " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Acceptable.setEnabled(false);


                                      }
            });
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I added my the actual JSON

Answer (score 5):

Why do you have a push ID around every user? That makes it necessary to query, and I doubt it is needed. A much simpler solution is to store users under their UID:

```
Users
  4pG0...y2
    address: "..."
    phone: "..."
    status: "status"
```

With this structure you can modify the status of a user with:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

rootRef.child("Requests").child(uid).child("status").setValue("new status");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how you db is structured but this might help

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    Unacceptable.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(context, " this Request has been Acceptable " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Requests").child("status").setValue("Your Request has been Acceptable");

                    Toast.makeText(context, " this Request has been Acceptable " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Acceptable.setEnabled(false);

}
```